# Microsoft.Bcl.Async is not working in Windows XP

Tags: .net-4.0, async-await, windows-xp

I am developing desktop application in WPF on .NET Framework 4.0, because of Windows XP on some client computers.

I need async/await in .NET 4.0 so I added references to Microsoft.Bcl.Async (latest NuGet release). Anytime I use Async/Await keyword, program crashes with following exception when started in Windows XP (works in Windows 7+):

```
Could not load file or assembly 'System.Core, Version=2.0.5.0,
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e, Retargetable=Yes' or
one of its dependencies. The given assembly name or codebase was
invalid. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131047)
```

Answer (score 4):

After extensive research, I found that it is needed to have installed [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2468871) update in Windows XP in order to Microsoft.Bcl.Async to work.